# Saving a Google Map to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-maps, google-drive-android-api

I've programatically created a google map in Android using the Google Map API / MapFragment.  Now I've finished putting my markers etc on, I'd like to be able to save this map on Google Drive (just like you can using the native Google Maps android App or the web based site).  Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Too broad. do you mean to say save a screenshot of the map or the whole map? Also what have you tried?

Comment: OK.  Using the google maps website, if I create a map it obviously saves it somewhere and it also creates a small .gmap link file.  What I need to know is how to save the map I have created in my android map (not as a screen shot) just as if i had created it via the website.